# fontconfig differentiate between sans and sans-serif

Tags: fonts

Trying to configure fontconfig to make font "Sans" map to "Times", and "sans-serif" map to "Helvetica", no matter what I try, both Sans and sans-serif map to the same font. Config:

```
<alias>
  <family>sans-serif</family>
  <prefer>
    <family>Helvetica</family>
  </prefer>
</alias>
<alias>
  <family>sans</family>
  <prefer>
    <family>Times</family>
  </prefer>
</alias>

<match>
  <test name="family">
    <string>sans-serif</string>
  </test>
  <edit binding="strong" name="family" mode="append">
    <string>Helvetica</string>
  </edit>
</match>

<match>
  <test name="family">
    <string>sans</string>
  </test>
  <edit name="family" mode="append">
    <string>Times</string>
  </edit>
</match>
```

Results:

```
$ fc-match "sans"
   Times.ttc: "Times" "Regular"`
$ fc-match "sans-serif"
   Times.ttc: "Times" "Regular"   <-- want this to be Helvetica!
```

Interestingly, any string beginning "sans-" matches against Times now:

```
$ fc-match "sans-ssdsdxcc"
   Times.ttc: "Times" "Regular"
```

Whereas "sans serif" matches against some other font:

```
$ fc-match "sans serif"
   GoudyBookletter1911.otf: "Goudy Bookletter 1911" "Regular"
```

Comment: I can't recall I have seen a fontconfig config file which distinguishes between `sans` and `sans-serif`. _Times New Roman_ is a `serif` style font. Are you sure you don't want `serif` for Times and `sans-serif` (or `sans`) for Helvetica?

Comment: I'm trying to match Chrome on OSX, which renders the css rule font-family:"Sans" with Times, and all other sans-serif with Helvetica. Either way, is it not possible to differentiate between sans and sans-serif in fontconfig?

Comment: Don't know for sure. That's why I posted a comment and not an answer.

Comment: [This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sans-serif) suggests that `sans` and `sans-serif` is the same thing.